# Basic question about heavy-tailed distribution

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, distribution

I have a basic question about heavy-tailed distributions.

Suppose there are 50,000 cities in Spain and the population of each is denoted by *p(1), p(2), …, p(n)*. Based on the mean of the distribution  and the deviation , how can we tell if the distribution is heavy-tailed or not? What procedure should we consider?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all 50,000 observations then you can calculate the central moments about the mean.

In particular, the fourth central moment divided by the variance squared is the kurtosis. This number will tell you if the distribution is platykurtic or not. If it is greater than three, it means that your distribution has heavier tails than a standard normal distribution.

So if you are working in Python and all 50K observations are stored in `x`:

```py
from scipy import stats

# Calculate kurtosis
k = stats.moment(x, 4) / x.var()**2

# Evaluate
if k > 3:
    print('Distribution has heavy tails')
else:
    print('Distribution does not have heavy tails')
```